# agg(count) in Apache Spark not working

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Trying perform aggregation my dataframe in Apache Spark (PySpark) using aggregation.

```
+----+---+---+
|name|age| id|
+----+---+---+
|Mark|  4|  1|
|Mark|  4|  2|
|Mark|  5|  3|
|Mark|  5|  4|
|Mark|  5|  5|
|Mark|  6|  6|
|Mark|  8|  7|
+----+---+---+
```

I have the following code that gives me a distinct count of records for one row:

```
old_table.groupby('name').agg(countDistinct('age'))
```

I try to add a normal count as another output of the aggregation, but it throws an error:

```
old_table.groupby('name').agg(countDistinct('age'), count('age))
```

Error:

```
NameError: name 'count' is not defined
```

Is there any way to add count to the distinct count to my output, such that I will have an output table like below?

```
+----+-------------+-----+
|name|countDistinct|count|
+----+-------------+-----+
|Mark|            4|    7|
+----+-------------+-----+
```

Comment: Can you show us what you're importing?

Comment: What packages I'm importing? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. I suspect you just need to do `from pyspark.sql.functions import count`. But I'd recommend something like `import pyspark.sql.functions as F` and then use `F.count` and `F.countDistinct` respectively.

Comment: That's perfect, I just checked and that is what I was missing, I had forgotten to import the count function, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You are using the `built-in` function 'count' which expects an iterable object, not a column name.

You need to explicitly import the 'count' function with the same name from `pyspark.sql.functions`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import count as _count

old_table.groupby('name').agg(countDistinct('age'), _count('age'))
```